# Converting a list of strings into part of a f string in Python

Tags: python, f-string

I have a list of error messages:

```
errors = [
    "this is an error",
    "this is another error",
]
```

I am then sending this as an email using Amazon SES:

```
ses_client.send_email(
        Destination={
            "ToAddresses": [
                "email@email.email",
            ],
        },
        Message={
            "Subject": {
                "Charset": "UTF-8",
                "Data": "Processed tracking file",
            },
            "Body": {
                "Text": {
                    "Charset": "UTF-8",
                    "Data": f"Finished Processing tracking file\n\n"
                            f"Sent {NUM_OF_EMAILS} emails"
                            f"\n".join(ERRORS)
                }
            },
        },
        Source="email@email.com",
    )
```

However, this seems to mess up the fString with the first error being the first line of the message, then the `Finished Processing tracking file` bit followed by the remaining errors.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You probably managed to have single string with all the lines of text, so it prints each error _joined_ by that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit string joining only apples to string *literals*, not arbitrary `str`-valued expressions. The three string literals involved here are

1. `f"Finished Processing tracking file\n\n"`
2. `f"Sent {NUM_OF_EMAILS} emails"`
3. `f'\n'`

These are implicitly joined into a single `str` value; *that* string is the one that invokes the `join` method on `ERRORS`, not just the `f'\n'` you intended.

Since you want to join the first two strings to the *result* of the call to `str.join`, you need something like

```
...
"Data": f"Finished Processing tracking file\n\n"
        f"Sent {NUM_OF_EMAILS} emails" + 
        f"\n".join(ERRORS)
...
```

to implicitly join the first two strings before explicitly joining the result with the return value of `f'\n'.join(ERRORS)`.

I would recommend avoiding implicit string joining altogether, and be explicit about what strings you want to join:

```
...
"Data": "Finished Processing tracking file\n\n"
        + f"Sent {NUM_OF_EMAILS} emails" 
        + "\n".join(ERRORS)
...
```

(and only use f-string literals when you need them).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
"\n".join([
    f"Finished Processing tracking file\n",
    f"Sent {NUM_OF_EMAILS} emails",
    "\n"
] + errors
)
```